# repaint() not invoking paintComponent(), even with Timer class

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a program which uses two timers (one to update the x,y of Objects on the screen) and another one to call `repaint()` for the `JPanel`. Originally I was using `Thread.sleep()` and while loop to accomplish this task but after reading other posts I realized I should use timer.

The program doesn't work if the `Timer` delays are 50 milliseconds (for both timers), and is VERY VERY laggy at 1000 milliseconds (after some time this too stops calling `paintComponent`).

Is there any way to make it make it work with less lag?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Not sure why you have 2 Timers. Just invoke repaint() after changing the x/y values in the first Timer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, sorry im a newbie, but how do i put the code on my post?

Comment: @camickr Thanks, I tried that and I still have the same problem. I even tried to do Graphics g = panel.getGraphics(), and then paintComponent(g), but the same problem arises.

Comment: Additionally, my repaint method just calls g.draw(bufferedImage, x, y, this); (Nothing to complicated to hold the thread). My panel is in a canvas style where I just keep slapping on the buffered image every 1000 millis

Comment: *"how do i put the code on my post?"* Use the [edit] link below the post. But note that I did not mean 'your code', but an MCVE / SSCCE. Read the links for details. Also, please use code formatting for the MCVE / SSCCE, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: `I even tried to do Graphics g = panel.getGraphics(),` - never do that. Until we see the `MCVE` we can't help.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. Turned out that since I was using the thread from the Action Listener method on another panel (due to card layout) to do the drawing, nothing was actually drawing till the thread exited.